# Why do body parts sometimes get a itching and tingling feeling when falling asleep?

Tags: sleep

Just before I fall asleep I sometimes experience an itchy and stinging feeling in my body parts. It can be that the nose or neck suddenly start to itch or a tingling stinging feeling in the legs. Sometimes my fingers also start to do small uncontrolled movements.

What is this about?

Comment: This is not a duplicate.

Comment: Not a dupe of http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/31107/involuntary-twitches-and-apnoea-during-early-phases-of-sleep

Comment: @FloriOn Why is this marked as a duplicate? My question is not about PLMD nor apnoea.

Comment: Sorry everyone, removed.

Comment: Maybe you're being allergic at something from your bed (maybe dusts). Try sleeping with clean bed clothing and pillows (and yourself too) and see if the itching persists.